Why does the “fine tuned universe” imply design?
I’m having trouble understanding this argument and where the intuition even comes from. I saw Christopher Hitchens say that this is the best theist argument and I have no idea how to even make sense of it.
So from what I gather, there are certain constants in the laws of physics where if they were even a bit different, life would not cease to exist.
But from doing further research, it seems that if they were a bit different, almost anything we see around us would not exist. Planets would not exist. Stars would not exist. Black holes would not exist. Asteroids would not exist. And those things are way more plentiful than life. So why doesn’t anyone argue that the universe is fine tuned for those things instead of life?
Secondly, what do they mean by “if the constants were different”? Sure, we have a set of equations where we can still write equations with different constants. But why do these different equations mean anything? We only see a universe that follows the current scientific laws, not imagined laws.
We can always imagine an infinite number of alternative scenarios to the current scenario. Why does this mean anything? And why does it point to design? I’m genuinely confused

Have you actually studied what is affected, the implications of fine tuning, and what the results would be if these fundamental things are off by even a miniscule amount?  Because understanding that will make chunks of your question apparent.  In any case, you are asking several questions here... this needs focus.

People do argue it's fine tuned for toothbrushes, volcanoes, etc besides life (e.g. Tim Maudlin). And if the scientific laws create a situation where it's like a pencil stood on its tip and every volume around it is a bomb (paraphrasing Nima Arkani-Hamed regarding physical constants/laws almost perfectly cancelling out without a deeper reason why they do and where the neighboring possibilities are a degenerate universe sans life, planets, etc), why wouldn't that mean anything interesting worth exploring?

You keep asking questions in a way that suggests your only knowledge of the issue is a couple of tweets you read. This site welcomes beginners but you are expected to put in a bit of your own effort researching the issue before you post a question.

So no answer? @DavidGudeman

It might be better to ask this question -- without specific references, without explanation who "they" are supposed to be, so also without much effort to be precise about what the claims are supposed to mean -- on a reddit site such as /r/philosophy. Supposedly you did "further research". Ok, then what are your references? I've voted to close this question; I'd be willing to undo that given some decent references. (Just to be clear, SEP or wiki I do not consider as such.)

@mudskipper almost none of the questions here have references included in them

@Syed, I answered one of your questions but almost the entire answer was correcting your misunderstandings. Your response to that answer suggested that you aren't here to learn, but only to argue. Not that there's anything wrong with that if you are still young. I started out in philosophy the same way; I was sure I was right about everything and just wanted to argue with all the idiots who disagreed. Then I grew up and started actually reading philosophy and learned that I had misunderstood much of what I was arguing about. But this isn't the site for that kind of arguing.

@DavidGudeman all I hear is unsubstantiated condescension and no actual arguments being made. That’s not going to work on me. Point out what exactly in my question I said is wrong or buzz off

@Syed, you are hearing correctly. I'm not going to waste time pointing out your errors when you aren't interested in learning but only in arguing.


We can always imagine an infinite number of alternative scenarios to the current scenario. Why does this mean anything? And why does it point to design?

The argument was crafted by people hoping to create proof of a god (a Christian one). It is marketing material so to speak. As such the design aspect is due to who created the argument and for what purposes, not about the facts leading to some conclusion.

I saw Christopher Hitchens say that this is the best theist argument

This does not mean he said it was a good argument. It just means Hitchens thinks the other arguments are even worse, even easier to debunk. Most arguments for gods are god-of-the-gaps arguments. And most such gaps are not really gaps for people with a good scientific education. But the constants of this universe can likely never be explained with a scientific prior cause, as such there is a seeming gap that is less likely to go away than all the other gaps that gods have been used to fill in history.
This is by no means the only gap that can be filled by gods of the gaps. Many other question may never have a meaningful explanation, like "why did that tornado hit this house but not the next? Why do men have nipples? Why did the chicken cross the road?" Some spiritual guidance tries to guide humans to give up on such or even all questions on meaning and reasons.
The question about causes or reasons if the universe however is likely to interest and vex most many humans.

Why should we think fine tuning requires a further explanation in the first place?

@Syed, "this answer assumes an explanation is there..." No, it assumes the constants of this universe can likely never be explained...  "Why should we think fine tuning requires a further explanation in the first place?" You asked, please tell us why do you think it requires an explanation?

But it's your question "Einstein", if you truly don't think it needs explaining then just stop asking already! There are some things we will just never know, you might benefit from accepting that fact.

@Syed, there is no philosophical reason to think that everything, including the universe, must have a cause. Some gaps for gods of the gaps  are "why did this person win the lottery? Why did that person have a car accident? Why did the tornado hit that house" Humans like having reasons and explanations, and religions like providing gods to fill in.

@MichaelHall I said we don't know if it needs explaining in the first place, and saying that there is a "gap" implies that we do. Not sure how else to make this clearer

I chose the term "gap" because it is short, handy, and harmonizes with "God of the gaps". And I made it clear that there can be seemingly gaps where there are actually none.

@Syed, my point is that you keep using the rhetorical "we".  Own your question and stop pretending you speak for the masses.
